# Is there a way to transform rectangle into any shapes in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

In MS Excel, I applied conditional formatting to a cell A1 so that it's color changes from blue at value 0 and red at value 100. I copied that cell and pasted it as linked picture(I) specially.(Paste Special). The color of the rectangle picture now changes if value in original cell is changed. The problem is, the shape is only rectangular, it can be converted into square and diamond shape at best.If same rectangle can be transformed into different shapes(maybe by adding extra anchor on rectangle shape), a heat map can be created easily. Please share your insights about this thing if there is a way.
Following pictures may help understand the problem:
[Example][1]

Comment: What does conditional formatting have to do with shapes in MS Excel?

Comment: When conditional formatted cell is copy and picture pasted, the change in value in original cell changes the color of shape. The shape can be enlarged, rotated but can not be changed into another shapes. Is there a way to transform it?

Comment: How do you put a "shape" in a cell? MS Excel shapes are like images, they aren't in a cell, they're overlaid; so I can't see how conditional formatting can affect them as it only affects the content of a cell. The very fact that I need to ask this means that PHPExcel won't do what you want; I don't even understand what you want

Comment: `color of the rectangle picture` - what 'rectange picture' you refer to? to a cell that have a rectangular background? You know that cells **are** rectangular, right? and that it is background color, not a picture? If you want pictures, look at embedding objects, excel supports that and you can access that through VBA. Then, if you want a heat map.. why dont you just generate a normal image?

Comment: I have just updated the question. Please take a look at that. and I am not familiar with PHPExcel, I tagged it because, it could create more advanced and customized features than excel..shape transforming and joining works only for very regular boarder countries only.. and I am trying it for irregular boundaries.

Comment: `shape is only rectangular, it can be converted into square and diamond shape at best` - that's not "conversion". If these things on the screenshot were "shapes" (OLE embedded objects) then it was simply rotated. Maybe just pick a different shape than rectangle. There are arrows which could work as crude triangles.. there are other shapes too..

Comment: `very regular boarder countries only` - boarder countries..? did you mean `border contours`?

Comment: @ quetzalcoatl, not a cell. I meant the diagonal large rectangle.... Is there another way to create heat map? Could you share that?

Comment: quetzalcoatl   There are arrows which could work as crude triangles.. there are other shapes too       But we can not link data with those shapes inserted from insert tab... only shapes that links data is copy and picture pasted (paste special) shapes.

Comment: Ok, I tried out this "paste as Linked Picture" option, and indeed it works as you described. Hower, you are wrong - this works also with other shapes, right out of "insert" box. Take your example - cell, copy, paste as linked picture. Then edit the source cell - picture will be updated. Click on the linked-picture. In "Formula" box on the top of the screen you will see something like `=$B$5`. Copy that. Now insert an arrow, or any shape that can have a text label. Put it into worksheet. Select it and try writing it a label. If it's ok and if it got label, go formula and write/paste `=$B$5`

Comment: I then tried it and worked fine as you mentioned. the value in the cell is linked to new inserted shape(from insert tab)... Now my problem is, the new shape can not acquire the color as specified by number.. put it simple, the cell was initially conditionally formatted before pasted as linked picture so as it appeared white when 0 inputted and complete red when 100 inputted..

Comment: I have recently changed the question showing recent improvement made by me. But the map looks very very rough. How can I improve it?

Comment: 1) photo is gone, please correct; 2) I dont know what you added to the question, change log shows you only erased few words, please review that; 3) see my "answer"

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems your answer certainly helps. However, I am not qualified to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a heat map, please consider using a CHART not gazillions of picture objects, colored/placed/rotated/etc to ... mimic a chart.

First, google anything about "surface chart" in Excel, see how it looks in Excel, whatever. Just see it and think about it so you can compare it to your current approach.

You will observe some things, like:

- it's 3D
- it has just a few layers/colors
- etc.

But really, all of them can be solved. Probably easier than your current approach.

- you can easily turn off both axes and you can rotate it so the camera is totally straight top-down - then it looks flat as paper and noone can see it as 3D anymore
- you can add more layers, you can set each of them to specific colors
- etc.

Some resources:

- [multiple colors in surface chart](https://superuser.com/a/568618/233273)
- [how to change rotation of 3d chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-rotation-or-perspective-of-a-3-D-chart-d4be8861-72b4-40f3-8bad-d0b5453b29f9)
- geesh, I just found even a **whole [article/tutorial dedicated to creating heat map charts](http://peltiertech.com/contour-and-surface-charts-in-excel-2007/)**.

Please, read that last link and I'm pretty sure you will want to use that approach instead of doing picture puzzles.